# Campany name "Co&Co" causes console error

Tags: html, wordpress

The HTML below causes console error saying "missing a ;" I have tried

`- Co&Co
- Co & Co
- Co&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp`

All give same error, any ideas how I can display Co & Co ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the issue? Perhaps provide a link to your site that has the console error. Are you trying to output the text from jquery or php?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using the `<pre>` tag! This works because `<pre>` is meant for displaying text EXACTLY how it is. Which means you can put virtually anything in the `<pre>` tag as long as it's not the `</pre>` tag or PHP code.

```css
pre{display: inline;}
```

```html
<span>This is a test! The following text, <pre>Co & Co</pre>, fits in this sentence <b>perfectly!</b></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Co&amp;Co`
`Co&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Co`

Either above works. You are missing the final `;` on the third line of code you provided. The first two lines simply wouldn't work.